# How to 'clear' (or fail) a PayPal eCheck in the sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created an eCheck payment in the PayPal sandbox and this now has a status of `Pending` and indicates it will clear in a few days. Obviously waiting this long is less than ideal for testing!

In trying to find out how I can force the sandbox transaction to clear (or fail, or otherwise update its status) I have found various links, including this one:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1257&actp=RSS

This (and other pages that I cannot link to here due my low reputation) suggest that there should be links to 'clear' or 'fail' the transaction when logged in as the buyer in the sandbox. However, when viewing the transaction in my buyer's sandbox account, these links are not present.

[This is how the bottom of the transaction details page appears for my buyer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcpoE.png).

If it makes any difference, the payment was initiated via the PayPal REST API, and the funding source was changed to eCheck during payment by the 'buyer' sandbox account.

I would like to know if it is still possible to manually clear a sandbox eCheck, and if not, how are we supposed to test eCheck functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but if you enable 'Payment Review' in the sandbox, you can simulate something close to the eCheck payment flow.

To do this:

1. Go [here](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)
2. Open the profile of your sandbox seller account.
3. Open the Settings tab and enable the Payment Review option.

Now, sales that you create with this seller will have a status of 'pending' after they are executed.

You can then allow the payments to complete (or fail them) by logging in to the sandbox as your seller, finding a pending transaction in your account history, clicking on it and using the special sandbox 'accept'/'reject' links you will find at the bottom of the page.